# Moving character controller on twisted track

Tags: unity, physics, character-controller

I am trying to move a ball using Unity's character controller component. I want to move the ball along the twisted track so that it can go upside down.

Below is the video of the problem when moving using Unity's Character Controller:
https://gfycat.com/dismalaridjoey

I want the ball to move upside-down along the twisted track.

I have the following questions:

1. What kind of modifications are required to achieve this using a
   character controller?
2. Which other methods (physics or splines) can be used to implement such ball movement? I am flexible to switch the appraoch.

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: How have you implemented your character and/or track movement so far? Are you required to use a character controller for this?

Comment: Yes, I have used Unity's Character Controller to move the ball as shown in the video. I am flexible to change the current approach.